# Axios and Webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, axios

I'm really new to Webpack and I'm using axios with a React project. I installed axios via npm and then I'm importing it like so when I want to use it:

`import axios from 'axios/dist/axios.min.js';`

Webpack takes care of the rest. Is this the "right" way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the standard way of doing this is as follows:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

The UMD build (axios.min.js) can be helpful when you need to include axios in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can do it the above way which is the **ES6** way (I prefer it), or the **Require.js** way which is: `const axios = require('axios');`. Make sure you are using Babel with ES6 such as `package.json` with `dependencies` having `npm install babel-preset-es2016 --save-dev`. I also toss in these fellows:    `npm install babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env --save-dev` (Though they may already be loaded through a dependency.